# How skip string already parsed in [spacy] doc

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Am working with a code that split hashtags with multiple word list: 1) One full of city names, 2) another with specific terms, 3) two big and common wordlist (spanish & english), in order to detect city names in hashtags and then geolocate them. The script works ok, but its's really slow, becouse will look for lots of substrings in the city list array after a similar word it's finded in wordlist and then is validated in Geonamecache library | https://github.com/yaph/geonamescache

Am trying to skip hashtags that already pass trough the tokenizer or at least those that the LanguageComponent already tag.

I have this code:

```
@Language.component("custom_set_extension")
def custom_set_extension(doc):
    #Diccionario General
    wordlist = initialize_words("wl")
    #Diccionario particular en el que se buscan palabras juntas como San francisco y Sanfrancisco (util para hashtags)
    citieslist_arr = initialize_words("cities").splitlines()
    #print(wordlist)
    Token.set_extension("is_geo", default=False, force=True)
    Token.set_extension("geo_countrycode", default=None, force=True)
    Token.set_extension("geo_hashtag", default=None, force=True)
    #print(type(wordlist))
    for token_index, token in enumerate(doc):
        if token._.is_hashtag:
            #print("token es hashtag en componente",token.text)
            if token._.is_geo:
                print("ya tiene data geo") #Should skip token but it always go to parse_tag() func
            else:
                parse_tag(token, token.text, wordlist, citieslist_arr)
            #if token.text in wordlist:
            #    print("lo encontró")
            #    print(token)
    return doc
```

It detects *is_hashtag* attribute but doesn't work wih *is_geo* and always execute parse_tag() function

```
@Language.component("mention_hashtags_set_extension")
def mention_hashtags_set_extension(doc):
    hashtag_getter = lambda token: token.text.startswith('#')
    Token.set_extension('is_hashtag', getter=hashtag_getter, force=True)
    mention_getter = lambda token: token.text.startswith('@')
    Token.set_extension('is_mention', getter=mention_getter, force=True)
    return doc
```

So is there a way that Spacy marks already tokenized strings/words in this case hashtags so i can use this mark as a conditional to skip the whole process of spliting the hashtag, looking for substrings in the arrays and then validating in Geonamescache, and making this process faster?